# How can I make the ternary operator execute code in PHP?

Tags: php, ternary-operator

I want to echo a simple message but in this form:

```
$number = 1;
$number == 1? echo 'yes': echo 'no';
```

NOT in this form:

```
$number = 1;
echo $number == 1? 'yes': 'no';
```

Is that possible? How: Why not;

Comment: Are you sure the second code snipped not worked for you : https://eval.in/628457

Comment: Works for me. What is your PHP version?

Comment: It doesn't work because that's not how it was made to work. If they wanted the ternary to work like that, they would have made it work like that. @lisectech has the closest solution to what you would *like* to do.

Comment: The first form doesn't work, the second does. But I need to make it work as the first.

Comment: Then you have to do what *@lisectech* is suggesting. There is no way to make a syntax error not be a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to do this? The second code snippet you provided is a solution to the problem.

If not, then try this:

```
<?php
$number = 1;
$number == 1 ? print('yes') : print('no');
```

Comment: May I ask you why does it work with the function print and not with echo?

Comment: @user3646717 `print` behaves like a function while `echo` is not really a function, but a language construct.

Comment: But but but, php manual says print is also a language constuct http://php.net/manual/en/function.print.php do you know the real reason why it works with print and not with echo?

Comment: If you have already bothered to check out the PHP manual, you should have read http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php. It says: "echo (unlike some other language constructs) does not behave like a function, so it cannot always be used in the context of a function.".